# AngularJS optional route parameter in the beginning

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to configure my AngularJS app with optional route parameter.

The URLs that I need to support may have a locale at the beginning. e.g.

- /fr-FR/Welcome
- /Welcome

I tried the following

```
$routeProvider.when('/:locale?/Welcome', {
...
})
```

However, it seems, it satisfies the "/fr-FR/Welcome" case and not the "/Welcome" case.

Is it because I'm always prepending a "/" in the beginning.

Will the following work?

```
$routeProvider.when('/:locale/?Welcome', {
...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
       .when('/Book/:bookId', {
        templateUrl: 'book.html',
        controller: 'BookController',
        resolve: { 
        }
      })
      .when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
        templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
        controller: 'ChapterController'
      });
```

Also you can use for multiple language support like this tutorials

https://scotch.io/tutorials/internationalization-of-angularjs-applications

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Angular.
remember /:locale is not optional. it is route parameter which means its value could be different but it should be there to execute that route (controller and template).

like

/fr/Welcome

/en/Welcome

**fr** and **en** must be there which help angular to select that route.